# How to run jsonPath in local javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, jsonpath

I am trying to run javascript locally using visual studio Code runner plugin and I was trying the following code

```
var status = jsonPath(json, "$..status");
```

I got the following error : **ReferenceError: jsonPath is not defined** . What I might be missing? Do I need to import jsonPath ?

Comment: what environment? browser or node?

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in JSON Path implementation in the browser and Node.js. You have to import an external library and then reference it in your code. For example you can use `jsonpath-plus`:

`$ npm install jsonpath-plus`

```
const {JSONPath} = require('jsonpath-plus');

const result = JSONPath({path: '$..status', json});
```